# Protractor - javascript isPresent always returning TRUE

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor

So, I am accessing an application. There are multiple employee records. However, there are no duplicate records.
I am deleting an employee record and then trying to verify that the employee record has actually deleted.
I am trying to find the employee name using xpath and using isPresent function.
The problem is that though the employee record is deleted the output is always returning:

> **Employee present: true**

Here is the piece of code that I am using:

```js
    it('Delete Employee', function() {
            login_page.enterUsername(browser.params.username);
            login_page.enterPassword(browser.params.password);
            var employeelist_page = login_page.clickLoginButton();
            var greetings = employeelist_page.greetingText();
            expect(greetings).toContain('Hello');
            var empName = employeelist_page.getEmployeeName('Master Shifu');
            empName.getText().then(function(text) {
                console.log('Empoyee record to be deleted, found: ' + text);
            });
            employeelist_page.getEmployee('Master Shifu').click();
            //element(by.id('bDelete')).click();
            employeelist_page.clickDeleteButton();
            //browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
            var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
            browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 5000, "Alert is not getting present :(")
                    browser.switchTo().alert().accept().then(function(){
                        var employeelist_page1 = require('../page/employeelist_page.js');
                        employeelist_page1.getEmployee('Master Shifu').isPresent().then(function(isPresent){
                            if(isPresent){
                                console.log('Employee present: true');
                            } else {
                                console.log('Employee present: false');
                            }
                        });
                    });
    
        });
```

**Here is the output:**

> Empoyee record to be deleted, found: Master Shifu
> Employee present: true

**Here is the list of functions in employee page:**

```js
    require('./create_page.js');
    require('./edit_page.js');
    var employeelist_page=function(){
        this.greetingText=function(){
            return element(by.id('greetings')).getText();
        };
        this.clickCreateButton=function(){
            element(by.id('bAdd')).click();
            return require('./create_page.js');
        };
        this.clickEditButton=function(){
            element(by.id('bEdit')).click();
            return require('./edit_page.js');
        };
        this.clickDeleteButton=function(){
            element(by.id('bDelete')).click();
        };
        this.getEmployee=function(empname){
            //return element(by.cssContainingText("#employee-list > li", empname));
            return element(by.xpath("//ul[@id='employee-list']/li[contains(text(),'" + empname + "')]"));
            
        };
        this.getEmployeeName=function(empname){
            //return element(by.cssContainingText("#employee-list > li", empname));
            return element(by.xpath("//ul[@id='employee-list']/li[contains(text(),'" + empname + "')]")).getText();
            
        };
        //this.clickEmployeeName=function(){
            //element(by.xpath('//ul[@id="employee-list"]/li[contains(text(),"Vladimir Putin")]')).click();
        //  getEmployee().click();
        //};
        
    };
    module.exports=new employeelist_page();
```

Comment: Do you mean: Master Shifu or 'Master Shifu' ?

Comment: Yes Vishal, it's 'Master Shifu'. While writing the question I replaced the variable value with this constant and at that time, I forgot the quotes.

Comment: Ok.Please share the 'getEmployee' method code as it is central to this problem.

Comment: Hi Vishal, updated the question to include the functions on Employee page

Comment: Check for 'isDisplayed' instead of 'isPresent'.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal , tried but that didn’t work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a expected Condition to wait for page re-load after confirmation of delete pop-up. Basically as I understand ,you need to give sometime to get the element removed from the DOM.

Example Code:

```
var EC =protractor.ExpectedConditions; 
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be no longer present on the dom. 

browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf($('#abc')), 5000,"Element still exists");
```